# simple Java distance calculator.

Tags: java

Whenever I run x1 (or any other int) as a number with a decimal (e.g. 3.7) I get the error message below. I have tried to find out what causes the error but since I'm not a very good Java programmer (yet :) ) I cant seem to figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

**The error message:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at MathAvstand.main(MathAvstand.java:12)
```

**The program:**

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MathAvstand {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("x1: ");
        double x1 = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("x2: ");
        double x2 = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("y1: ");
        double y1 = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("y2: ");
        double y2 = keyboard.nextInt();

        double a = x1 - x2;
        double b = y1 - y2;

        double summa1 = Math.pow(a,2)+ Math.pow(b,2);

        double avstand = Math.sqrt(summa1); 

        System.out.println("x1: " + x1);
        System.out.println("x1: " + x2);
        System.out.println("x1: " + y1);
        System.out.println("x1: " + y2);
        System.out.println("Avståndet mellan punkterna är: " + avstand); 


    }

}
```

Comment: hint - InputMismatchException might mean input mismatch

Comment: You might also want to look into input validation instead of actually trusting that the user will in fact, enter a valid number...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the calls from [`Scanner.nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) to [`Scanner.nextDouble()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble%28%29) like

```
double x1 = keyboard.nextDouble();
```

an `int` is not a floating point number.

Comment: Sorry my bad, used . instead of ,

Comment: @Hevar You might want to look at [`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) if you want to format decimals in your locale.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Just added: DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".0"); 
and it works great!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error called InputMismatchException because

```
  keyboard.nextInt()
```

is looking for an int, but you are passing it a double

try replacing all those with

```
keyboard.nextDouble();
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using a nextInt and then entering a double.

Try:

double x1 = **keyboard.nextDouble();**

Answer (score 0):

Call the method next() instead of nextInt() to fix it.
You could also as others have suggested change it to nextDouble(), this is just another suggestion.